# Sheaves in Philosophy

Tags: reference-request, philosophy

I once found a book on google.books. It was about the applications of sheave theory to philosophy or more general to social studies. I don't remember for sure. i just know it was not the book *Sheaves in geometry and logic* by Mac Lane/ Moerdijk.

Does anyone know a book with this topic?

Thanks for your time.

matthias

Answer (score 0):

synthetic philosphy of contemporary mathematics by zalamea
from pp285-